# Universal Voltage Divider Bias Circuit with both BJT and JFET

Tags: bjt, voltage-divider, jfet

I am dealing with the following circuit:

[image: Universal Voltage Divider Bias Circuit with both BJT and JFET]
I am trying to understand if I can just assume that, much like in the JFET voltage divider circuit, V_G = 10/(40+10) * 16V , or if the presence of the BJT after the JFET will affect the voltage at this point.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

The current into the base of the BJT is about \$\beta\$ (100) times smaller than the current through the emitter/collector. The upshot of this is that the effect of the 1k2 resistor as seen at the base can be regarded as the same as a grounded base resistor that is 100 times higher or 120kohm. This will make Vg a few percent lower.